# Image strategy in iPhone app

Tags: iphone

I'm writing a card game for the iPhone, and I'm not sure about the best strategy for displaying the cards.  I have a basic prototype that creates a UIImageView that can be dragged for each card with a dummy image.  I wanted to use one large UIImage that contains the faces of all of the cards, and then have each draggable UIImageView display a part of that image.  I must be misunderstanding what setBounds is for - I thought that controlled which part of the underlying image is displayed.  So, two questions:

1. Is this the right approach?
2. How do I display just a part of the image?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your resolution, this might not be the best approach.

From [Apple](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> You should avoid creating UIImage
>   objects that are greater than 1024 x
>   1024 in size. Besides the large amount
>   of memory such an image would consume,
>   you may run into problems when using
>   the image as a texture in OpenGL ES or
>   when drawing the image to a view or
>   layer. This size restriction does not
>   apply if you are performing code-based
>   manipulations, such as resizing an
>   image larger than 1024 x 1024 pixels
>   by drawing it to a bitmap-backed
>   graphics context. In fact, you may
>   need to resize an image in this manner
>   (or break it into several smaller
>   images) in order to draw it to one of
>   your views.

Now, you are talking about breaking it up into several smaller pieces, but given UIIMage's caching, I am not sure what happens to memory every time you access the image and copy a sub-rect out of it.  I think the approach I would take is to have an array of images, instead of one big one.